# Runtime Exception in android studio : Could not instantiate mapper:xstream .jar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new in android development, at the run time fatal exception occurs:

```
`com.ymapps.restaurants.mobifooddemo.single E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ymapps.restaurants.mobifooddemo.single, PID: 930
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.ymapps.restaurants.mobifooddemo.single/com.ymapps.restaurants.YMAMainActivity}: com.a.a.a: Could not instantiate mapper : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.EnumMapper :     com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.EnumMapper

        Caused by: com.a.a.a: Could not instantiate mapper :   
        at com.a.a.c.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.a.c.g(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.a.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.a.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.a.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.a.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.a.c.<init>(Unknown Source)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/mapper/EnumMapper
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.EnumMapper
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.EnumMapper
```

Xstream1.4.7.jar is added to libs folder.

This shows error in .java file

```
   import android.content.IIntentReceiver;
   import android.content.pm.IPackageManager;
   import android.net.IConnectivityManager;
   import com.google.android.collect.Lists;
   import com.android.internal.app.IVoiceInteractor;
   import libcore.io.DropBox; 

  etc
```

I can't understand the problem.I think xstream class not recognized with app..
 xstream1.4.7.jar file already added as library

```
   build.gradle file:
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   compile files('libs/xstream-1.4.7.jar')
```

what should I do? Please help me..
Thank you

Comment: post more code... the problem is in `MyAppMainActivity` as your log indicates, but you did not post the entire error nor the entire Activity code.

Comment: I have edited my question.plz refer it and give appropriate solution..thank you